# Magento Store Not Displaying product pages but showing error

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product

I am desperately trying to setup a magento site and I am fairly new to the platform.

I am getting an error on the product page that says:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 900006666823
```

This error occurs for every product.

When I look at the logs I see this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:97:"Invalid method 
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array ...
```

I have seen some threads that mention php extensions not being enabled and i have checked the extensions and this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Does anyone have any idea where I could look to have this resolved?

Thanks in advance,
Noob Programer
aka Trent

Comment: oh. and P.S. if you would like to see what I am talking about try clicking any product on this page: http://bifrostcomputing.com.au/computer-hardware/cases/atx.html

Comment: Add your coding part which have method "displayProductStockStatus"

Comment: Can you go to /path/to/magento/var/report and give us the contents of the file called 900006666823? Also if you want to print your exceptions while developing you can turn on dev mode in index.php.

    //if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
        Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    //}

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);